# how wrap the buttons items in a linkbar in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I'm working with a `LinkBar` component with  a dataprovider that changes dynamically. Users can add and delete items from the `LinkBar` using an admin tool.

The problem is if the user adds many items in the `LinkBar` its width increases until it shows a scrollbar in my container.

I would like it to work so that when the user adds items, the `LinkBar` width is not changed but the height of the component increases instead and the additional buttons "wrap" around to another row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to skin / override the LinkBar and trap the update. That way you can force it to a new / 2nd line instead of continuing to draw horizontally.